# Returning TypeScript interface member issue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I work on Vue.js app with TypeScript, but I'm not much in TypeScript.

The code looks as following:

interfaces.ts:

```
export interface UnitFound {
  payment_message: string;
}
```

MapBlock.vue:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { UnitFound } from "@/Interfaces";

export default defineComponent({
  ...
  computed: {
    PaymentMessage() {
      const found: UnitFound = this.units.find((element: any) => element.id === this.selectedUnitId);
      return found.payment_message;
    }
  },
  ...
});
</script>
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_message' of undefined"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't a TS error, `found` is undefined

Comment: If I remove .payment_message and return found only, I'm getting the object and there is payment_message.

Comment: Are you making any async calls?

Comment: unrelated, but don't use `any` if you are coding with TypeScript ;) Referring to: `(element: any)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`this.units.find()` can return `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) if it doesn't find a match, which could happen if:

- `this.units` is initially empty
- `this.units` is not empty, but does not contain an element with an `id` that matches `this.selectedUnitId`

You could address this by using the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator (and defaulting to an empty string):

```js
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    PaymentMessage() {
      const found: UnitFound = this.units.find(/*...*/);
      return found?.payment_message || '';
    }             
  },
})
```